# Is there a function such that $f(xyz)=f(x)f(y)f(z)$, for any $x,y,z\in G$ but $f$ is not an endomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> I am required to show that, for a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $(G,\cdot)$ a finite group of order $n$, if $n$ is even there is a function $f:G \rightarrow G$ such that $f(xyz)=f(x)f(y)f(z)$, for any $x,y,z\in G$ but $f$ is not an endomorphism. Is this true for $n$ odd?

I chose $\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}f(x)=\ord(x)$, but I am unsure that $\ord(xy)=\ord(x)\ord(y)$ for any $x,y\in G$.

At least I obtained that it is not a morphism if it respects that property, because indeed as for $e=a^{kl}a^{ph}a^{-1}$, where $(k,p)=1$ and $kl+ph=1$, $f(e)=f(a^{kl}a^{ph}a^{-1})=-klph$, which is false if $f$ is a morphism.

Comment: What have you tried? It's false for $n=1$, and most likely you've tried some small values such as $n=2,3$: what did you get? And write "every" instead of "a" which is unclear as it may mean "some". Next, $f(x)=\mathrm{ord}(x)$ is not a self-map of $G$, but is a map from $G$ to $\mathbf{N}$.

Comment: Your proposed function doesn’t work because in general, the order of a product is not the product of their orders. For a simple counterexample, consider the case in which $x=y^{-1}$, where $xy=e$.

Comment: First of all, $ord$ is not a function from $\mathbb G$ into $\mathbb G$.

Answer (score 5):

First of all note that $f(e)=f(e)^3$ and so $f(e)^2=e$. This gives us a hint about $f(e)$.

So if $n$ is even then pick $g\in G$ such that $g^2=e$, $g\neq e$ (which exists by [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory))) and define $f(x)=g$, i.e. the constant function at $g$. Obviously $f(xyz)=f(x)f(y)f(z)$ regardless of what $x,y,z$ are. But since $g\neq e$ then $f$ is not a group homomorphism.

Now if $n$ is odd then the condition $f(e)^2=e$ implies that $f(e)=e$ (this time by [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory))). And therefore for any $x,y$ we have

$$f(xy)=f(exy)=f(e)f(x)f(y)=ef(x)f(y)=f(x)f(y)$$

and so $f$ is a group homomorphism.

> but I am unsure that $ord(xy)=ord(x)ord(y)$ for any $x,y\in G$.

If $G$ is non-trivial then that never holds for all $x,y$. Consider $x\neq e$ and $y=x^{-1}$. You can also easily check that $ord$ does not satisfy the original condition as well, i.e. consider $ord(exx^{-1})$.

Also talking about $ord$ does not make sense to begin with since the codomain of $ord$ is $\mathbb{N}$, it's not even a group. Not to mention that domain and codomain are different although that assumption is unnecessary.